# Flutter iOS build warnings

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios, xcode14, flutter-ios-build

When I try to archive my flutter product for release I am getting lot of warnings as shown below.

> Minimum deployment iOS version: 12
>
> Xcode version: 14.2

My POD file for installation as below:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
    end
  end
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this line in your podfile at `root/ios/Podfile` to the desired target version.
[image]
Then you'd ideally reinstall all pods or do a `repo update`

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Already has that enable in podfile like platform: ios, '12.0'. but still getting those warnings. I don't know what I am missing here. Please help me with this.

Comment: I tried, flutter clean.. flutter run.. flutter build ios --release, it's still getting the same error while archiving. I am stuck with this.

Comment: try `cd ios` followed by `pod install --repo-update`